# Best way to determine actual H3 hexagon size?

Tags: h3

What is the best way to get the actual size of an H3 hexagon (area or edge length) given an `H3Index` and not the average constant provided by the H3 API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**:
H3 now includes functions for exact area and edge length measurements - [documentation here](https://h3geo.org/docs/api/misc).

**Original Answer**:
At present, the H3 library doesn't expose any functions for this (though we've [considered it](https://github.com/uber/h3/issues/312), and may add in the future). At present, we've decided that the H3 library is no better placed to calculate pure geographic areas/distances/etc than any other geo library, so the best option is to find another geo library in your language of choice and apply it to the output of `h3ToGeoBoundary`.

You can see an example of doing this in JavaScript in [this Observable notebook](https://observablehq.com/@nrabinowitz/h3-area-stats).

Comment: I decided to use the `GeoBoundary` struct to make the calculation manually; you're right about there not really being a need for it since this is possible. I just posted a question about it, however.

Comment: your link in update section is broken

Comment: @kidcoder Thanks, fixed

Comment: I get allways zero value for `h3.exactEdgeLength("8c29a1d756b49ff", (<any>h3).UNITS.m);` - (for any hex) may be you know why? (I use typescript and h3 by `import * as h3 from 'h3-js';` - it has some problem with UNITS but even if I type string "m" it still returns ZERO) - ?

Comment: `h3.exactEdgeLength` takes a unidirectional edge, not a cell index. See https://h3geo.org/docs/api/uniedge

Comment: @nrabinowitz - oh - now I see - thank you :)